# Compare two integer arrays for similar values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm attempting to write a method in order to compare & match integers (0-9) in array X (method parameter) with Y, an integer from X can only be matched with ONE integer from Y if the integer is presented multiple times. E.g. x[3]=7 can only be matched with either y[4] or y[5], but not both. Total number of matches should be returned.

Assuming both arrays are sorted descending

```
int[] x = {0,1,4,7,8,9};
int[] y = {1,2,3,5,7,7,8};


x[0] no match i y[i]
x[1] match with y[0]
x[2] no match i y[i]
x[3] match with y[4] only
x[4] match with y[6]
x[5] no match i y[i]

Total number of matches = 3
```

Help is much appreciated.

what I have tried so far is the following... 
It however returns only 2 as count.

```
class Test {

    public static int matchArrays  (int[] x) {
        int[] y = {1,2,3,5,7,7,8};

        int index = 0;
        int count = 0;
        while (index < x.length) {
            for (int i=0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if(x[index]==y[i]) {
                    count++;
                    break;
                }
            }
            index++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {0,1,4,7,8,9};
        System.out.println(matchArrays(x));
    }
}
```

Comment: So is there a specific question?  WHat have you tried?

Comment: you can use contains() method

Comment: My apologies, I have updated my question with what I have tried so far...

Comment: Please use the debugger. I would also suggest refactoring the code to separate the finding of number in array and counting of finds into different methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using streams you can do something like:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){            
        int[] x = {0,1,4,7,8,9};
        System.out.println(matchArrays(x));
    }
    public static int matchArrays  (int[] x) {
        int[] y = {1,2,3,5,7,7,8};
        return (int)Arrays.stream(x).filter(i->Arrays.stream(y).anyMatch(j->j==i)).count();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, although I was in the end able to solve the issue via nested loops this solution is so much more elegant. I have to sure read up on streams as my knowledge of stream operations is very limited.Thanks again.